# How do I get the path alias without the language code?

Tags: 8, path-aliases

Suppose I have an alias like http://www.example.com/en/the-new-webpage.html.

I want to get the *the-new-webpage.html* part in `hook_preprocess_html()`. The language code might change into 'ja' or some other code due to the language availability. So I can't get the URL and pass it to `str_replace()` to replace the language part. Is there a function or a way to get the alias part without the language code?

Answer (score 2):

Since you just need the last part of the path, you can use the following code in a `hook_preprocess_html()` implementation.

```php
$current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
$alias = \Drupal::service('path.alias_manager')->getAliasByPath($current_path);
if (basename($alias) == 'the-new-webpage.html') {
  // Your code here
}
```

Starting with Drupal 8.8.0, some Drupal core service has been renamed, as described in [The Path Alias core subsystem has been moved to the "path_alias" module](https://www.drupal.org/node/3092086). As consequence of that, in Drupal 8.8.0, Drupal 9.x, and Drupal 10.x, the *path.alias_manager* service has been replaced by the *path_alias.manager* service.
The previously shown code needs to be changed to the following one.

```php
$current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
$alias = \Drupal::service('path_alias.manager')->getAliasByPath($current_path);
if (basename($alias) == 'the-new-webpage.html') {
  // Your code here
}
```

The [*path.current*](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.services.yml/service/path.current/9) service has not been renamed, neither in Drupal 9.x nor in Drupal 10.x.